# Why is this operator< overload function invisible to STL algorithms?

Tags: c++, std, juce

I have learned to overload `operator<` in order to make custom classes compatible with STL algorithms, just like this:

```
struct A
{ int a; };

bool operator< (const A& x, const A& y)
{ return x.a < y.a; }

std::vector<A> aOne, aTwo, aResult;

std::set_difference(aOne.begin(), aOne.end(),
                    aTwo.begin(), aTwo.end(),
                    std::inserter(aResult, aResult.begin()));
```

However, when I try to do the same thing with a [ValueTree](https://docs.juce.com/master/classValueTree.html) object from the JUCE library, it fails:

```
bool operator< (const juce::ValueTree& x, const juce::ValueTree& y)
{
   // let's now worry about the implementation of this function here...
   return true;
}

std::vector<juce::ValueTree> vOne, vTwo, vResult;

std::set_difference(vOne.begin(), vOne.end(),
                    vTwo.begin(), vTwo.end(),
                    std::inserter(vResult, vResult.begin()));

// COMPILER ERROR: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::less<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const'
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with my `operator<` function?

I am aware that the answer probably has to do with the inner workings of `ValueTree`, and that this is therefore an imperfect question. But I have no idea of the *type of* thing that could be going wrong here. To my eyes, the two cases seem entirely symmetrical, so I don't know why one would fail while the other succeeds.

Please note: I am aware that I have left my arrays unsorted, and that `set_difference` would therefore throw an exception. Right now I'm just trying to get the code to compile, and keeping the example brief.

Comment: *"I am aware that I have left my arrays unsorted"* Empty vectors are sorted. And for the MCVE, it is indeed not needed to have more.

Comment: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ro-namespace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be found by ADL, you have to put your operator in the same namespace as the class:

```cpp
namespace juce
{
    bool operator< (const ValueTree& lhs, const ValueTree& rhs) { /*..*/ }
}
```

Comment: Ah, so simple! Thanks for pointing this out. Strangely, I tried it with other juce objects (and without the namespace declaration), and it worked fine. But your suggestion does solve the problem.